# Build access matrix from raw data with python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that look like this (pandas dataframe):

```
| User  | Resource |
|=======|========= |
| User1 | Res_1    |
| User1 | Res_8    |
| User2 | Res_1    |
| User2 | Res_2    |
| User3 | Res_8    |
| User3 | Res_3    |
| User1 | Res_3    |
```

How can I build matrix like this from that data:

```
      | Res_1 | Res_2 | Res_3 | Res_8 |
User1 |   +   |   -   |   +   |   +   | 
User2 |   +   |   +   |   -   |   -   |
User3 |   -   |   -   |   +   |   +   |
```

I used df.groupby("Resource"), but I don't understand how to iterate items in groups for building required matrix.

How to get required result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html#pandas.pivot_table):

```
>>> df.pivot_table(index='User', columns='Resource',
...                aggfunc=lambda _ : '+', fill_value='-')
Resource Res_1 Res_2 Res_3 Res_8
User                            
User1        +     -     +     +
User2        +     +     -     -
User3        -     -     +     +
```

or [`.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) followed by [`.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html#pandas.DataFrame.unstack) and [`.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna):

```
>>> df.groupby(['User', 'Resource']).aggregate(lambda _: '+').unstack().fillna('-')
Resource Res_1 Res_2 Res_3 Res_8
User                            
User1        +     -     +     +
User2        +     +     -     -
User3        -     -     +     +
```